# get the result from mysql+php and shows in titanium

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have developing the one application using titanium.

Here the values are inserted successfully.But i didn't get the success message from webservices code.

I have using following code for insert a databaase :

In titanium side code :

```
function StaffRegistration(){ 
if($.staff_firstname.value != "" && $.staff_firstname.value != null){ 

                 var request = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 

              onload:alert(this.responseText), 

              onerror: function(e){ 

                  Ti.API.debug(e.error); 

                  alert(this.responseText); 

              }, 

              timeout:1000, 

                 });    


                 request.open("POST","xxx/xxx.php"); 

                 var params = ({"staff_firstname": $.staff_firstname.value,"staff_email": $.staff_email.value,"staff_password": $.staff_password.value,});  

              request.send(params); 

          } 



          else{ 

                 alert("Please enter the firstname"); 

          }               



         Ti.API.info("Result for registration = " + this.responseText);



   };
```

I have using a following php(webservice code) :

```
<?php  
  $request          = base64_decode($_POST['jsondata']);
  $data             = json_decode($request,true);

 $staff_firstname           = $data['staff_firstname'];
   $staff_email             = $data['staff_email'];
  $staff_password           = md5($data['staff_password']);

     include "db_connect.php";

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT staff_email,staff_firstname from at_staff WHERE staff_email = '$staff_email'");

    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
  while($queryresult=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $uname[]=$queryresult['staff_firstname'];
      $uemail[]=$queryresult['staff_email'];
 }
if(in_array($staff_firstname,$uname) and in_array($staff_email,$uemail)) {

    $response='{"Error":"1","Message":"Username and Email already exist"}';
    echo $response;
} else if (in_array($staff_firstname,$uname)) {
    $response='{"Error":"1","Message":"Username already exist"}';
    echo $response; 
} else {
    $response='{"Error":"1","Message":"Email already exist"}';
    echo $response;
}
        } else {
        $response='{"Error":"1","Message":"Successfully Registered"}';
    echo $response;
$data=array("staff_firstname"=>"'".$staff_firstname."'",
            "staff_email"=>"'".$staff_email."'",
            "staff_password"=>"'".$staff_password."'"

            );


    echo $response;
        }

      ?>
```

How can i get the $response in titanium from this webservice url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2218667

```
Ti.API.info("Result for registration = " + this.responseText);
```

will NEVER work as you show in the first piece of code .

why ? because you send a request which will take like 1 seconde (for exemple), obviously, your programm won't wait 1 sec after

```
request.send(params);
```

i will continue the programm and when the request return a result, it will get into

```
onload(e) :
```

and here only you will be able to have your $result.

is this ok? well now, if this.responseData isn't effective, I don't have the solution .Can you check your line : "} else {" ,i supose there is a if above in the code? are you sure $result is defined upper?

Can you try the same request without titanium with a basic html form to be sure $result is write correctly in this case, like this, we will know if the problem come from php or from the link betwin php & titanium.

Answer (score 1):

well , i supose it's asynchronous request, so the folowing may not work

```
Ti.API.info("Result for registration = " + this.responseText);
```

coud you try :

```
        onload : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText); // maybe Ti.API.info(this.reponsedata) according to your php.
        },
        onerror : function(e) {...
```

in my mind, if you receive JSON information (it trully look's like), you need

```
this.responseData //instead of this.responseText
```

Comment: Hi I have added above line.but I didn't get the $response on my titanium .Am getting the following [INFO] :   Result for registration = undefined...But the value's are inserted successfully....so please give me a solution.how can I get the $response ?